# What is mean by X-CDN?

Tags: http, header

I had search though the web, it is hard to find the meaning of X-CDN in term of **http header field**. What is the function of `X-CDN: Incapsula`? I just know it is something related to cache, but I don't know the actual function of the `X-CDN: Incapsula`.

Comment: Headers beginning with `X-` are custom ones that every application can specify as it likes.

Answer (score 1):

`X-CDN` is an HTTP header which is the name describing the CDN being used. Example values are Incapsula, fastly, cloudfront and level3. As far as I can tell, it is simply informational.

https://docs.mux.com/docs/cdn-configuration